# Aren't classes in Java equivalent to structures in c

Tags: java, c, class, structure

I just started learning java yesterday since i want to make android apps. So far i only know c. I am reading a book called "Head first java" and it keeps talking about object and classes which are pretty new to me. I just have one question and if someone can clarify this for me that'd be very helpful: 
What is/are the difference(s) between classes(java) and structures(c)?
ps: I'd also love if you can recommend me a book that really is for absolute beginners because the book i'm reading right now doesn't have enough details for those that are completely new to object oriented programming. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Class and Structure in PHP and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920849/difference-between-class-and-structure-in-php-and-java)

Comment: @AnubianNoob: incorrect. See, for example, [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/).

Comment: There are similarities, but there are huge differences.

Comment: @AnubianNoob about c structures, you are correct but c++ structures suppoet few more features.

Comment: @vanza But GObject is effectively "cheating". It's like adding an abstraction over Java for MI. It's no longer trivially Java, but a run-time added "on top of" Java. Or, another way to view it: it's like writing Objective-C without the syntax additions.

Comment: C++ is object oriented like Java. C is procedural and has structs which are basically groups of primitives. It has none of the object-oriented capabilities of Java.

Comment: @user2864740: there's nothing in the C spec that says what gobject does is not allowed, so I don't see why it's cheating. It may be ugly as hell, but they're not cheating.

Answer (score 7):

No. You don't get inheritance, methods, abstract methods, polymorphism, and many more object oriented concepts with Structs.

You can try to make C conform to object oriented behavior using structs, but that's different from using an object oriented language.

Comment: I agree with this answer (on a general level). While one can *add* support for such concepts through the addition of a separate run-time (and conventions), this functionality is *not* part of C structs. As such, using GObject is a counter-example is effectively arguing that "structs are classes" because one can use them to *implement* such features.

Comment: @vanza C++ and C are not the same. In C++ structs and classes are identical except for the default access modifiers. C, on the other hand, has no support for the OO stuff.

Comment: @Pete no one mentioned C++ anywhere.

Comment: @vanza That's a bit like saying that Java classes are linked lists, just because you can implement linked lists using Java classes. Similarly, you can use C structs to _implement_ polymorphism, but they aren't polymorphic themselves.

Comment: @yshavit (et al) you missed my point. The answer says you *cannot* have those features, when it's possible to add them. I never said that the built-in c-compiler-provided structs have those features.

Comment: @yshavit Precisely. The original C++ compiler was actually just a translator that converted C++ to C and it fudged the object oriented stuff using structs. That doesn't make C an object oriented language, but you can make it act like one if you bend and twist it enough.

Comment: @vanza I guess it comes down to what you define as "having" those features. I think, given the context of the question, that it means that the language gives them to you, built-in. Or would you consider assembly a functional language, just because there's nothing a functional language has that you can't "have" (by your definition) in assembly?

Comment: @yshavit: the answer simply states that you "cannot have" those features, which is plainly wrong because gobject has them using structs. You're trying to stretch my comments way beyond what I'm trying to say here. To your point, I don't consider C an OO language, but as Pete said, that doesn't prevent you from building OO concepts on top of C code.

Comment: @vanza I have just made a trivial edit in the wording of the answer in order to satisfy your attention to such detail. I hope Anubian Noob doesn't mind.

Comment: @vanza To be clear, I wasn't trying to stretch your comments to imply that you think assembly is functional. Rather, I was suggesting that your comments may be nitpicking the language of the answer, and that it really comes down to what one means by "having." In the context of the question, I don't think "having" means "able to implement using other built-in features," but maybe that's just me. Regardless, I think Marko's edit clarifies it well.

Comment: @yshavit: you might consider it nitpicking, but "doesn't have" and "cannot have" are very different for me. But, Marko's edit makes it better.

Comment: @vanza you are totally correct, this is why i've been saying forever that turing machines clearly have classes and garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

"Aren't classes in Java equivalent to structures in c?"

Short answer, No.

My answer is too short cause the differences is the difference between two completely different paradigms, and it needs a complete book (not even a chapter) like : "Thinking in java".

Answer (score 3):

Java classes perform several roles, only one of which is (implicitly) defining the layout of the data structure called the *instance* of that class, but you are right in thinking that *objects* are essentially data structures, just like instances of `struct`.

The main difference is that C's `struct` is something much more raw and "close to the metal" than a Java class. Basically, with much additional framework code and strict adherence to many conventions you could reimplement a good part of Java's objects, but the syntax would not be as clean as in Java.

There are many other differences, such as what exactly is covered by compiler's static checking, automatic memory management, etc. In the end, differences outweigh similarities, but as a point of understanding, it is not wrong to compare Java objects with C structs.

Answer (score 1):

I know, that I am contradicting the view of a lot of people here, but you are right, a class really is nothing more or less than a struct with a lot of bells and whistles.

To be precise, the C++ language actually specifies that an instance of a class without virtual functions and/or virtual inheritance *has the same memory layout as a C struct with the same data members in the same order*.

All that is added to the `struct` to provide runtime polymorphism is a single v-table pointer, which is used to look up the virtual members. Inheritance is generated by including the base class structures as data members of the child class `struct`.

Of course, when you think about it for a second, you realize that classes *must* be implemented with `structs`, one way or another. C++/Java classes must be implemented somehow, after all. And it helps to remind yourself that object orientation is not primarily a language feature, it is a paradigm that can be used in *any* imperative programming language. It can be used in Java, in C++, in C, in Pascal, in Fortran, and even in assembler. All which the so-called object oriented languages add, is syntactic sugar to handle all the technical stuff of object orientation.

Nevertheless, it is important to learn all the bells and whistles when you start working in C++ or Java.

Comment: Good point, but I disagree. We are talking about C, not C++. In C, structs do nothing but hold other primitives and structs.